# Login successfully but HTML element not found

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, python-3.8

I am learning web **scraping** with Selenium for Finance team project. The idea is:

1. Login to HR system
2. Search for Purchase Order Number
3. System display list of attachments
4. Download the attachments

Below are my codes:

```
# interaction with Google Chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# specify chromedriver location
PATH = './chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'

# open Google Chrome browser & visit Purchase Order page within HRIS
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
browser.get('https://purchase.sea.com/#/list')

< user input ID & password >

# user interface shows "My Purhcase Request" & "My Purchase Order" tabs
# click on the Purchase Order tab

try:
    po_tab = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "My Purchase Orders"))
    )
    po_tab.click()
except:
    print('HTML element not found!!')

# locate PO Number field and key in PO number
try:
    po_input_field = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "input-field"))
    )
    po_input_field.send_keys(<dummy PO num#>) ## any PO number
except:
    print("PO field not found!!")

# locate Search button and click search

try:
    search_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search"))
    )
    search_button.click()
except:
    print("Search button not found!!")
```

I stuck at the step `# click on the Purchase Order tab` and following steps.
I can find the elements but I can see error after executing the py script. The most interesting part is....I can do it perfectly in Jupyter Notebook.

Python Script Execute Error
[image]

Here are the elements after inspection screens:

## Purchase Orders tab

[image]

## PO Number input field

[image]

## Search button

[image]

Comment: Please post the `HTML`

Comment: @NandanA HTML is too long. How do I provide here?

Answer (score 0):

See you are using `presence_of_element_located` which is basically

> ```
> """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM
> of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
> locator - used to find the element
> returns the WebElement once it is located
> """
> ```

What I would suggest to you is to use `element_to_be_clickable`

> ```
> """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
> page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed
> but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
> locator - used to find the element
> returns the WebElement once it is located and visible
> ```

so, in your code it'd be something like this :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "My Purchase Orders"))).click()
```

Also, we could try with different locators if this does not work, locators like `CSS`, `XPATH`. But I'll let you comment first if this works or not.

Comment: both ways failed. it is very interesting to note that the idea works on Jupyter Notebook but failed on python script.

Answer (score 0):

The first error in your log is `HTML element not found!` You are performing a click before element is `visible` on `DOM`. Please try below possible solutions,

- Wait till element is visible then perform click operation.

```
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "My Purchase Orders"));
```

- If still you are not able click with above code then wait for element to be clickable.

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "My Purchase Orders"));
```

I would suggest to create reusable methods for actions like `click()` `getText()` etc.

Comment: both ways failed. it is very interesting to note that the idea works on Jupyter Notebook but failed on python script. yea, i will create functions for click() once I put together everything. For the moment, I wil implement my idea in Jupyter Notebook.